# renderEvent that doesn't work in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to add an event in FullCalendar.io through a function javascript.

I have tried in two ways.

Recalling to end page a function or with a click.

I don't receive error but in my calendar the event is not added.

```
<div id='calendar'></div>


<script language="javascript">
id='13-17-1'
title='TextOK'
start= '2016-04-07T08:30:00'
end= '2016-04-07T09:30:00'
test=addCalanderEvent(id, start, end, title)


function addCalanderEvent(id, start, end, title)
{
var eventObject = {
title: title,
start: start,
end: end,
id: id

};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true);
alert("OKOK")

}

</script>


<input type="button" onClick="addCalanderEvent('13-17-1','TITLE','2014-09-19T10:30:00','2016-04-19T10:30:00')">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample based off your code to add an event on button click

https://jsfiddle.net/Lra2535n/

```
/* fullcalendar 2.6.1, moment.js 2.12.0, jQuery 2.2.1, on DOM ready */

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({});


$('#addEvent').on('click', function() {
  // Random event id for demo...
  var id = Math.random().toString(26).substring(2, 7);
  addCalendarEvent(id, '2016-04-08', '2016-04-11', 'An added event ' + id);
});

function addCalendarEvent(id, start, end, title) {
  var eventObject = {
    id: id,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    title: title
  };
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true);
}
```